# Can't Display different Database

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence, performancepoint

Goal:
Select a specific database named contoseRetailDW based on the list of different database in Peformance Point Dashboard application.

Problem:
The servername is correct but unfortunately a list of different database don't display.
What am I missing in order to display different database

Background info:
I'm using a the role as administrator that is based on windows authenfication. I'm using SharePoint BI enterprize and Windows Server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to look in the event log to solve your problem.

Comment: Where and how should I find the event log?

Comment: The computer application event log, and/or ULS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to [create a new Data Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191198%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in PerformancePoint.

The selection that you have checked in the screenshot is a "Standard Connection". The intent of this is to use an SSAS Multidementional datasource. From your other screenshots it looks like you are just trying to connect to a database engine i.e. A Tabular Datasource.

In PerformancePoint tabular datasources are only compatible with Filters and Scorecards. This is described in an msdn article titled [Planning for PerformancePoint data sources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928315%28v=office.14%29.aspx)